# How to enable X-Frame options in Liferay CE 7.4 for an specific URL - Embed a Liferay page in another Domain

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-7.4

I want to embed a page from my Liferay portal into another website using an iFrame, but I am getting this error:

`Refused to display '<DOMAIN>/regional-resources' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

I did a research and there is a property that was used to enable this functionality ([Liferay 7.4 doc](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.4-latest/propertiesdoc/system.properties.html)):

- `http.header.secure.x.frame.options=true`
- `http.header.secure.x.frame.options.1=/regional-resources`
- `http.header.secure.x.frame.options.255=/|SAMEORIGIN`

I tried it out but I got this error:

`ERROR [main][VerifyProperties:47] Stopping the server due to incorrect use of migrated portal properties [http.header.secure.x.frame.options, http.header.secure.x.frame.options.255]`

I can not find another documentation about this property, maybe I need to set it as an OSGI configuration file but not sure how.

Comment: I added the file `system-ext.properties` in the path /WEB-INF/classes/, I added a line per each URL: `http.header.secure.x.frame.options.10=<URL>` I followed the instructions in this [post](https://itsliferay.blogspot.com/2017/06/set-x-frame-options-in-liferay-dxp.html#:~:text=*%22.%20%23%20http.header.secure.x.frame.options=false.%20If%20you%20disable%20this,through%20iframe%20and%20it%20cause%20any%20security)